# How can I adjust these functions to work even at the extremes of the range of values? (Inverse LOG)

Tags: c++, math, floating-point, percentage, logarithm

I am writing a automated bot for an mmorpg, one of the necessary pieces of information is the players current heading.  The way the cameras view angles are stored in memory is rather complicated. I have access to three variables which I have named CamX1, CamX2 an CamY.

CamY is a floating point value ranging from -.91 to +.91, 0 is perpendicular.  A tricky thing though is the values is adjusted from its percentage to this value by passing it through a base 10 logarithm, you can see what I mean by looking at the code below that turns the value back into a percentage by using an inverse logarithm.

CamX1 is also a floating point value ranging from -1 to positive 1.  When looking due W or due E the value is 0. When looking south the value is negative, when looking north the value is positive.  This variable is extremely concluded because the value is passed through a base 10 logarithm but also the max value when looking due N or due S varies from .41 to 1 based on the current value of Y.  You can understand this better by looking at the code for converting CamX1 to a percentage.

CamX2 is the same as CamX1 except rotated 90 degrees, so instead of 0 when facing W or E it is 0 when facing N or S. Positive when E and negative when W. it is at it's max value when facing W or E but that maximum value varies like CamX1 based on the cameras current Y view angle.

The code below works with the exception of when you are facing within 10 degrees of any cardinal direction, for example: when facing 350 - 360 degrees the value is always 350, one you cross over due north the value jump to 10 degrees and does not change until you pass 10 degrees, if you are facing 80 degrees - 90 degrees the value is 80 degrees, 90 - 100 degrees is 100 degrees but 101 is 101 and so on.  The same issue exists with the Y value but only when within 10 degrees of 0, the value from -10 to 0 is -.1 and once you cross 0 the value is +.1 until you pass 10 degrees and then it increases correctly.  If you can explain the problem just with the Y variable I can most likely apply that to the problem with the X values and have a complete solution. Here is the code:

```
float GetYFactor()
{
    float yAsPercent = (pow(10,abs(CamY)/.91))/10;
    if (yAsPercent > 1) yAsPercent = 1;
    return 1-(yAsPercent*.59);
}

float GetX1ViewAngleAsPercent()
{
    float x1AsPercent = (pow(10,abs(CamX1)/GetYFactor()))/10;
    if (x1AsPercent > 1) x1AsPercent = (1 - GetX2ViewAngleAsPercent());
    return x1AsPercent;
}

float GetX2ViewAngleAsPercent()
{
    float x2AsPercent = (pow(10,abs(CamX2)/GetYFactor()))/10;
    if (x2AsPercent > 1) x2AsPercent = (1 - GetX1ViewAngleAsPercent());
    return x2AsPercent;
}

float GetCurrentHeading()
{
    float deg = GetX1ViewAngleAsPercent() * 90;

    if(CamX1 > 0 && CamX2 > 0) //Q1
        deg = 90 - deg;
    if(CamX1 < 0 && CamX2 > 0) //Q2
        deg = 90 + deg;
    if(CamX1 < 0 && CamX2 < 0) //Q3
        deg = 180 + (90 - deg);
    if(CamX1 > 0 && CamX2 < 0) //Q4
        deg = 270 + deg;


    return deg;
}
```

The reason for the code such as

```
if (yAsPercent > 1) yAsPercent = 1;
```

is probably related to this problem, at the near maximums the value of the percentages would increase past 1 and go up to about 1.15, and that was my attempt at a quick fix. but it doesn't really fix the problem entirely.

I know this was a long read so thank you for your time, any help supplied would be greatly appreciated as i need accuracy of about +/-2 degrees so these 20 degree gaps are rather frustrating, also no need to worry about the case where any of the three values that we start with are exactly 0, it has never happened, try as I may.
I believe this has do do with passing values < .01 into the inverse logarithm function (10^.009) but I don't have enough experience with this type of math to understand whats going on.

Comment: It seems like if the value I'm passing into the inv. log is < .01 I could multiply it by 10 before and then divide by 100 instead of 10 afterword, ex:

10^.01/10 = .1 (bad)

10^(.01*10)/100=.01 (good)

but for some reason I feel uneasy about this... also if I tried this method for all values I end up with values way larger then they should be once I supply values > .01

Comment: Try using `double`?  I really don't understand your ranges, or the resolution you need.  Maybe a `long double`?

Comment: Have you tried using Fixed Point arithmetic?

Comment: I don't think it's a problem with the size of the variable, using windows calculator or wolfram alpha gives the same results.

Comment: Is there anywhere a documentation of the camera coordinate system? Or some code for the forward encoding from the camera heading to the coordinates?

Comment: I wish, its from a game that i am reverse engineering.

Comment: Then it would perhaps be helpful if you could add a number of numerical examples to your question that are computed by the original code, i.e., what the original code thinks is connected in triples (x1,x2,y) and camera orientations (quaternions?).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why anybody would encode angles with logarithms, there should be no problem with numeric over- or underflow in typical angle values.

A reasonable interpretation is that the pair (x1,x2) encodes the horizontal orientation, and y the elevation of the camera. Then the expected calculation would be

```
radians = atan2(x2,x1)
degrees = radians*180/pi
```

The value of y would not enter the calculation at all. It might be that some kind of radius or velocity information is encoded in the magnitude of (x1,x2) for instance as

```
0.5*log(x1^2+x2^2)
```

There is insufficient information to divine what really is the case.

Comment: In general, I think there are two reasonable choices to encoding angles, degrees and radians. Pick one. Encode **every** angle you store in that form.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan: This misses the point. Even if you want to store all angles in degrees, the built-in trig functions use radians, so you always have to add instructions for conversion. The big question, however, is, at what point do exponentials and logarithms enter the picture?

Answer (score 0):

I guess what I thought was the answer (as noted in the comment I posted) was the correct solution, or at least it is working, if anyone knows why I shouldn't do it this way please le me know. the updated code is below with the main change being the lines involving the local variable modifier. I also renamed CamX2 to CamZ.

```
    float GetYFactor()
    {
        float modifier = 1;
        if (abs(CamY) <= .1) modifier = 10;
        float yAsPercent = (pow(10,abs(CamY * modifier)/.91))/10/modifier;
        if (yAsPercent > 1) yAsPercent = 1;
        return 1-(yAsPercent*.59);
    }

    float GetXViewAngleAsPercent()
    {
        float modifier = 1;
        if (abs(CamX) <= .1) modifier = 10;
        float xAsPercent = (pow(10,abs(CamX * modifier)/GetYFactor()))/10/modifier;
        if (xAsPercent > 1) xAsPercent = (1 - GetZViewAngleAsPercent());
        return xAsPercent;
    }

    float GetZViewAngleAsPercent()
    {
        float modifier = 1;
        if (abs(CamZ) <= .1) modifier = 10;
        float zAsPercent = (pow(10,abs(CamZ * modifier)/GetYFactor()))/10/modifier;
        if (zAsPercent > 1) zAsPercent = (1 - GetXViewAngleAsPercent());
        return zAsPercent;
    }

    float GetCurrentHeading()
    {
        float deg = GetXViewAngleAsPercent() * 90;

        if(CamX > 0 && CamZ > 0) //Q1
            deg = (90 - deg);
        if(CamX < 0 && CamZ > 0) //Q2
            deg += 90;
        if(CamX < 0 && CamZ < 0) //Q3
            deg = (90 - deg) + 180;
        if(CamX > 0 && CamZ < 0) //Q4
            deg += 270;

        return deg;
    }
```

Comment: This idea is wrong. (10^x)/10=10^(x-1) is a correct identity, for small x it is also correct that 10^x=exp(x*ln(10)) is approximately 1+x*ln(10), while with your modification you would get a value 10^(10*x)/10=exp(x*ln(10)*10)/10 approx. 0.1+x*ln(10), which differs by about 0.9 from the first value.

Comment: I don't think i really understand you fully but what i did does seem to be working, unless you have an alternate working solution Ill probably keep it this way for now...